# Using a loop in Python to name variables

Tags: python, variables, for-loop

How do I use a loop to name variables? For example, if I wanted to have a variable `double_1 = 2`, `double_2 = 4` all the the way to `double_12 = 24`, how would I write it?

I get the feeling it would be something like this:

```
for x in range(1, 13):
    double_x = x * 2 
    # I want the x in double_x to count up, e.g double_1, double_2, double_3
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, but what would be the correct syntax for implementing the looped number into the variable name? I haven't coded for a while, but I do remember there was a way to do this.

Comment: use a dict. it is exactly why they were created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use a dictionary instead. E.g:

```
doubles = dict()

for x in range(1, 13):
    doubles[x] = x * 2
```

Or if you *absolutely* **must** do this **[AND ONLY IF YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND WHAT YOU ARE DOING](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=locals#locals)**, you can assign to `locals()` as to a dictionary:

```
>>> for x in range(1, 13):
...     locals()['double_{0}'.format(x)] = x * 2
... 
>>> double_3
6
```

There *never, ever* should be a reason to do this, though - since you should be *using the dictionary instead!*

Comment: +1, but `Or if you absolutely must do this` he probably doesn't and therefore shouldn't ever.

Comment: assigning to locals like this is very dangerous. really should be avoided. you should link some information about it or a more strict warning.

Comment: The [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=locals#locals) say to avoid modifying it.

Answer (score 7):

expanding my comment: "use a dict. it is exactly why they were created"

using defaultdict:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
```

using normal dict:

```
>>> d = {}
```

the rest:

```
>>> for x in range(1, 13):
    d['double_%02d' % x] = x * 2


>>> for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
    print key, value


double_01 2
double_02 4
double_03 6
double_04 8
double_05 10
double_06 12
double_07 14
double_08 16
double_09 18
double_10 20
double_11 22
double_12 24
```

Comment: no specific reason, but he wants ints, i guess you dont need that part really.. but i like them :P

Comment: ;) I'd rather have an exception if I try to access something that isn't there.

Answer (score 6):

Although I doubt you really need to do what you want, here's a way:

```
namespace = globals()
for x in range(1, 13):
    namespace['double_%d' % x] = x * 2

print double_1
print double_2
   ...
print double_12
```

`globals()` returns a dictionary representing the current global symbol table (the dictionary of the current module). As you can see, it's possible to add arbitrary entries to it.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, you should use a dict. Here's a nice easy way to create one that meets your requirements.

```
>>> {k:k*2 for k in range(1,13)}
{1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 12, 7: 14, 8: 16, 9: 18, 10: 20, 11: 22, 12: 24}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dict while it don't fit your requirement. But I hope it can help you.

```
var_dic = {}
for x in range(1, 13):
    var_dic["double_%s"% str(x)] = x * 2
print var_dic
```