# How to append pandas dataframe with similar names in a loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have pandas data frame numbered from x1,x2....x100 with same columns.

I want to append them all using a for loop. How can i do that? 
I know how to append two dataframe but how to do it for 100 of them. The main problem here is how can i have a dynamic variable name.

I want to append the data frames not concat.

> x=x1.append(x2) 
>   x=x.append(x3)
>   and so on.

I want to this in a loop.

Comment: Are they in separate variables or inside a list? Why can't you just use `pd.concat`?

Comment: I want to append the data frames not concat. 
x=x1.append(x2) 
x=x.append(x3)
and so on.

Comment: I understood what you want. I'm saying `pd.concat` will do that for you. What I'd like to know is how your dataframes are currently stored.

Comment: They are pandas.DataFrame . My Question is, Is there  a way I can call the name of the dataframe dynamically?
Like we can do that for a string : for i in range(0,100): Print "String" + str(i)

Comment: Ah, I understood. They are in separate variables. Well... you technically can query `globals`.

Comment: Can you please help me with the code?

Comment: Doing this with globals would make the solution almost too easy, but I'm hoping there's a way to avoid that. When you are creating your dataframes, why can't you append the dataframes `xi` to a list? Why do you keep them in 100 separate variables?

Comment: This has been asked like 100000 times. Use a list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603215/using-a-loop-in-python-to-name-variables