# Subtract a single value from columns in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply

I have two data frames, *df* and *df_test*. I am trying to create a new dataframe for each *df_test* row that will include the difference between x coordinates and the y coordinates. I wold also like to create a new column that gives the magnitude of this distance between objects. Below is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# Create Dataframe
index_numbers = np.linspace(0, 10, 11, dtype=np.int)
index_ = ['OP_%s' % number for number in index_numbers]
header = ['X', 'Y', 'D']
# print(index_)

data = np.round_(np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=(len(index_), 3)), decimals=0)
# print(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index_, columns=header)
df_test = df.sample(3)
# print(df)
# print(df_test)

for index, row in df_test.iterrows():
    print(index)
    print(row)
    df_(index) = df
    df_(index)['X'] = df['X'] - df_test['X'][row]
    df_(index)['Y'] = df['Y'] - df_test['Y'][row]
    df_(index)['Dist'] = np.sqrt(df_(index)['X']**2 + df_(index)['Y']**2)
    print(df_(index))
```

**Better For Loop**

```
for index, row in df_test.iterrows():
    # print(index)
    # print(row)
    # print("df_{0}".format(index))
    df_temp = df.copy()
    df_temp['X'] = df_temp['X'] - df_test['X'][index]
    df_temp['Y'] = df_temp['Y'] - df_test['Y'][index]
    df_temp['Dist'] = np.sqrt(df_temp['X']**2 + df_temp['Y']**2)
    print(df_temp)
```

I have written a for loop to run through each row of the *df_test* dataframe and "try" to create the columns. The *(index)* in each loop is the name of the new data frame based on test row used. Once the dataframe is created with the modified and new columns I would need to save the data frames to a dictionary. The new loop produces the each of the new dataframes I need but what is the best way to save each new dataframe? Any help in creating these columns would be greatly appreciated.

Please comment with any questions so that I can make it easier to understand, if need be.

Comment: Can not find any info about df_T1

Comment: Sorry about that, T1 is what I was using before (index). I have switched it. Good catch.

Comment: You may have some luck reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603215/using-a-loop-in-python-to-name-variables

Perhaps related, why is `df_test` a sample of `df`? This method creates index errors in pandas, when I try to run your code (and assign new `df`s to a dictionary).

Comment: df_test is a sample of df because I want to find the distances between all the objects(each row is an object with a x and y distance from some coordinate origin). I need to find the distances from each respective object in df_test to any object in the df dataframe. I'm open to other ways of doing this though. I am trying to go about it the only way I can think of right now.

Comment: So, if you have a DF of 10 coordinates, you want to get back a DF (or dict, or list) with 90 coordinates? e.g., index (dict key) is your original x-y, and your values are the distances to the other 9 coordinates?

Comment: Well, there are only 3 test objects so in this case there would only be 3 dataframes returned with 10 coordinates each; one of which is the test object at (0,0) now. What needs to happen now is each dataframe needs to be stored in a dictionary to be called upon at a later time. That is where I was trying to dynamically name each new dataframe created.