# Splitting up a dataframe into N pieces

Tags: python, for-loop, dataframe, macros, scikit-learn

**Context**

Hi all, i'm trying to split up my dataset into 180 unique pieces and then run it through a geocoder (my n is ~180,000 and the geocoder has a 1,000 batch limit). I'm pretty new to Python but some googling led me to `shuffle` within `sklearn.utils`. It seems to do the trick and this code here does what I want (conceptually):

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

df = shuffle(addresses)
df1 = df[0:1000]
df2 = df[1000:2000]
df3 = df[2000:3000]
```

However, I obviously don't want to sit down and manually construct 180 dataframes like this so am looking for a way to put it in a loop. This is my basic idea:

```
start = 0
end = 1000
for a in range(1,180):
    print(start, end, a)
    start = start+1000
    end = end+1000
```

The above works fine.

**Code that doesn't work**

However when I try and integrate the actual splitting into the loop (not just printing) it fails. I'm pretty sure the issue is in how i'm calling the macro `a` when i'm naming the dataframes. I have no idea how to solve this though.

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
df = shuffle(addresses)

start = 0
end = 1000
for a in range(1,180):
    df_str(a) = df[start:end]
    start = start+1000
    end = end+1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the  `exec()` function to execute the dataframes you created. Here, the "`format()`" method is used to change the name of the dataframe.
For example, `if a=1` then `{} = data'.format("df_%d" %(a)))` will rename the data as `df_1`

```
   start = 0
   end = 1000
   df_str = dict()
   for a in range(1,180):
       df_str[a] = df.iloc[start:end]
       data= df_str[a]
       exec('{} = data'.format("df_%d" %(a)))
       start = start+1000
       end = end+1000
       del data
```

If you want the dataframes to have indexes starting from 0 instead you can reset the index using reset_index(drop=True):

```
exec('{} = data'.format("df_%d.reset_index(drop=True)" %(a)))
```

Comment: An explanation of your code would help to improve the quality of your post. Please if possible, add comments or explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Potential fix:

```
df_str = dict()
for a in range(1,180):
    df_str[a] = df[start:end]
    start += 1000
    end += 1000
```

Possible previous bugs:

- Make sure you define df_str. Recommended to be a dictionary.
- It seems that you are calling df_str as a function with the round brackets, square braces is more commonly used for element access.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Siong. Unfortunately, this hasn't resolved my issue. My understanding is that I am defining df_; i simply want to add a suffix onto the string value df_ that takes the string value of integer `a`. This is what I have now:

`start = 0`
`end = 1000`
`for a in range(1,180):`
    `b = str(a)`
    `print(b)`
    `df_[b]  = df[start:end]`
    `start = start+1000`
    `end = end+1000`

Yet it returns `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: Your latest error is due to you define df_ as a string and a string is not mutable in python. You might want to explore structure like a dictionary. Then you can store the i-th sub data frame as the i-th entry.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment Siong. It still hasn't resolved my issue though. The dictionaries are empty after the loop. Besides, i don't think fitting this in with my other code is possible. I really need them in dataframes. Do you know a way to do that?

Comment: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13603268/8926905) might be of your interest.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into this more carefull. The post you link advises that I only do what i'm trying to if i absolutely know what i'm doing; I definitely don't but there is a tradeoff with how much time I want to invest in getting to that place before I actually solve the problem I have. Really useful though -- appreciated