# Python: How to get Dataframes with get_groups in for loops

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have grouped a DataFrame using `data.groupby('column)` and now I want to create a dataframe from each group:

```
for i in data_group.indices:
    i = data_group.get_group(i)
```

I can print the dataframes out within the for-loop, but I can't access them otherwise... Somehow the naming of the `DataFrame` with a variable is not working. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: As you iterate, store them in a list.  If they need names, store them in a dictionary and use the names as keys.

Comment: Why do you need them assigned to variables? Can you just use `.get_group('whatever')` when you need it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a loop in Python to name variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603215/using-a-loop-in-python-to-name-variables)

Answer (score 1):

You can store them in a list

```
g=data.groupby('column') 
l=[]
for x,df in g : 
    l.append(df)
```

Or using `get_group`

```
g.get_group('groupkey')
```

Comment: Even though this does not yield individual dataframes, but one dictionary with key-value pairs I can access them from outside the for-Loop.